# Pigeon Hole Principle about two disjoint non empty sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that for every subset S of {1,2, ..., n} having size 6, there are 2 disjoint non empty subsets of S having the same sum

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried anything? How could the pigeon hole principle be applied?